# How to experimentally perform a POVM measurement?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, quantum-measurements

Reading through Nielsen and Chuang, I came across the following example.

> Consider a POVM containing three elements,
>   $$
> E_1 \equiv \frac{\sqrt{2}}{1 + \sqrt{2}} |1⟩⟨1|,\\
> E_2 \equiv \frac{\sqrt{2}}{1+\sqrt{2}}\frac{(|0⟩ - |1⟩)(|0⟩ - |1⟩)}{2}\\
> E_3 \equiv I − E_1 − E_2.
> $$
>      It is straightforward to verify that these are positive operators which satisfy the completeness relation  m Em = I, and therefore form a legitimate POVM.

The point the author makes is that if I'm given one of two states, $|{\psi_1}\rangle=|{0}\rangle$ or $|{\psi_2}\rangle=(|{0}\rangle+|{1}\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$, performing measurements described by this POVM will distinguish the state some of the time but never make a misidentification error.

What does it really mean to perform a measurement described by a POVM? It's clear what I can do experimentally for projective measurements -- in a system like a neutral atom QC I can perform a measurement of some observable, and each projector is uniquely identified with an eigenvalue of the observable. N&C states that for a POVM $\{E_m\}$, the probability of outcome $m$ is $\langle{\psi}|{E_m}|{\psi}\rangle$, which makes sense. However, when we construct POVM elements like in this example though, I don't understand what the corresponding outcomes would be. Since that's not clear, I thus don't see what it means to perform a POVM measurement and how one would distinguish between measurement $E_3$ and $E_2$.

Comment: Please focus on one question.

Comment: I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: In experiments, you rarely perform perfect projective measurements. Rather, you perform some POVM which is somewhat close to a projective measurement.

Comment: But if you want to start from projective measurements, I recommend Preskill's lecture notes.  They take more the physicist's approach to teaching QI.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a POVM in an experiment?

Comment: Could you provide an example of a *true* projective measurement in an experiment?  --  Otherwise: Take an imperfect photon detector, for instance. Or any other device with imperfections.  --  More broadly: What people call a "weak measurement" is a POVM.  Put a weak beam splitter in a photon path and detect the reflected photon.

Answer (score 1):

If it is clear to you how to measure 'normal' (orthogonal) measurement then you can always implement any Povm as

1. Take another system (ancilla)
2. Act on both with a unitary transformation
3. Perform a joint orthogonal measurment

I will look up the paper proving this.

Comment: This is in any textbook on Quantum Information.